# Validate HTML from user

Tags: php, html, validating

How can I validate a HTML code submitted by the user? Looking for `<script>` tags is easy, but you can also embed JS in for example `<div onclick="yyy"></div>`. Are there any ready to use libraries/functions? (like `$safeHTML = validateCode($rawHTML)`)

Comment: Do you want to *validate* or *sanitize*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/).

Answer (score -1):

I use the following function:

```
function sanitizeString($var){
    $var = strip_tags($var);
    $var = htmlentities($var);
    $var = stripslashes($var);
    return mysql_real_escape_string($var);
```

It changes over characters like < to

```
&lt;
```

prevent escape characters for SQL, stips unwanted slashes, etc.

Comment: -1 This doesn't validate anything and looks like a bad collection of different stuff. `strip_tags()` might break your html, makes it unusable later and doesn't like malformed tags (something like `<<scr<ipt>script>`, or similar); `stripslashes()` might be useful only in the ever more rare event of magic_quotes enabled; `mysql_real_escape_string()` is a MySQL escaping function, and doesn't work without an open connection (returning FALSE from all your beautiful sanitizer) or with INTs; HTML and DB are irrelated destination,need to be treated as such. Escape only for the target, not _a priori_